# XQUERY: How to update HTML text, enclosing lines in <span> tags

Tags: xpath, xquery

I'm trying to update a fragment of HTML text with new information about each line. This is an example of HTML:

```html
<div>
  <span class="column1">
    <a id="l1"></a>aaaaa<span type="foo">aaa</span>aa
    <br id="l2"/>aaaaaaa
  </span>
  <span class="column2">
    <br id="l3"/>aaabbbb
    <br id="l4"/>bb<span>123</span>bbbbb
    <br id="l5"/>bbbbbbb
    <br id="l6"/>ccccccc
  </span>
</div>
```

And this is the new information:

```xml
<sections>
    <section n="1" type="intro" from="1" to="3"/><!-- @from and @to are line numbers -->
    <section n="2" type="main" from="3" to="5"/>
    <section n="3" type="conclusion" from="6" to="6"/>
</sections>
```

The goal is to be able to style lines differently depending on this new information (here for instance a division into sections). So the final output should look like this:

```xml
<div>
  <span class="column1">
    <a id="l1"/></a><span class="intro">aaaaa<span type="foo">aaa</span>aa</span>
    <br id="l2"/><span class="intro">aaaaaaa</span>
  </span>
  <span class="column2">
    <br id="l3"/><span class="intro main">aaabbbb</span>
    <br id="l4"/><span class="main">bb<span>123</span>bbbbb</span>
    <br id="l5"/><span class="main">bbbbbbb</span>
    <br id="l6"/><span class="conclusion">ccccccc</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is the xquery I have until now:

```
for $section in $sections/section
    for $line in $s/@from to $s/@to
        let $name := $section/@type
        let $br := $text//*[contains(@id, concat('l', $line))]
        let $newline := <span class="{$name}">{$text//*[contains(@id, concat('l', $line))]/following-sibling::node()[following-sibling::*[contains(@id, concat('l', $line+1))]]}</span>
    return
        ($br, $newline)
```

Obviously this is not working!

1. I have problems where a line belongs to two sections. For instance I get both 
   `<br id="l3"/><span class="intro">...</span>` and `<br id="l3"/><span class="main">...</span>`
2. if lines were grouped into `<span>` elements for columns (or other levels of grouping), this gets lost.

I haven't got a clue how to get to the desired output. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you use XSLT from your XQuery processor or is your XQuery processor e.g. Saxon 9 which also does XSLT? At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCSa I have implemented an XSLT 3 attempt (left some debugging info of the constructed/used map in there).

Comment: It first computes a map from your section data with the line number being the key of each map entry and a sequence of associated class strings being the value. Then it takes the HTML data and pushes it with `xsl:iterate` through a mode which for the current line number/map key transforms the relevant nodes using `for-each-group group-starting-with`.

Comment: As for XQuery, the maps can be computed the same way in XQuery 3.1, the `xsl:iterate` can probably implemented with `fold-left` and the `for-each-group group-starting-with` with `for window start when`. Of course the whole XSLT given template based match processing needs to be done by an XQuery function with typeswitch.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have thought of using xslt. The mapping is what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt to translate the XSLT 3 linked to in the comment to XQuery 3.1:

```
declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
declare namespace array = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array";

declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'html';
declare option output:html-version '5';

declare variable $sections as document-node(element(sections)) external := document {
<sections>
    <section n="1" type="intro" from="1" to="3"/><!-- @from and @to are line numbers -->
    <section n="2" type="main" from="3" to="5"/>
    <section n="3" type="conclusion" from="6" to="6"/>
</sections>    
};

declare variable $classes-per-line as map(xs:integer, xs:string*) := map:merge(for $section in $sections/sections/section, $line in $section/@from to $section/@to return map { $line : $section/@type/string() }, map { 'duplicates' : 'combine' });

declare function local:apply-templates($nodes as node()*, $line as xs:integer) as node()* {
    $nodes ! (typeswitch(.)
      case document-node()
        return document { local:apply-templates(node(), $line) }
      case element()
        return 
            if (self::*[*/@id = 'l' || $line])
            then 
                element { node-name() } {
                    local:apply-templates(@*, $line),
                    for tumbling window $w in node()
                    start $s when $s/@id
                    return
                        if ($s/@id = 'l' || $line)
                        then ($s, <span class="{$classes-per-line($line)}">{ local:apply-templates(tail($w), $line) }</span>)
                        else local:apply-templates($w, $line)               
                }
            else
                element { node-name() } { local:apply-templates((@*, node()), $line) }
      default
        return .
    )
};

document {
<html>
    <head>
      <title>fragement transformation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {serialize($classes-per-line, map { 'method' : 'adaptive' })}
    {
        fold-left(sort(map:keys($classes-per-line)), ., local:apply-templates#2)
    }
    </body>
  </html>
}
```

At https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8v/3 I have replaced the higher-order fn:fold-left with a simple local:fold-left which recursively calls local:apply-templates, to allow the code to work with Saxon 9.8 or later HE which doesn't support higher-order functions/function references.